# Sub routine definition what does $ mean

Tags: vb.net

Okay I have never used vb script and I am trying to convert a legacy vb module to c#. The syntax is fine but man this function definition just complete threw me for a loop.

What does `$ %` and `#` mean in the declaration.

Like for example `pop(name$,balance#, id%)`

Comment: Note that VBScript is **NOT** VB.NET.  To answer your question, the symbols are hold overs from legacy VB and denote the data type of the variable, IIRC.

Comment: They are the old BASIC (pre net; even in VB6 they were optional) type specifiers: $== string, #==Double, %== int

Comment: @Plutonix your'e the man

Comment: @Plutonix strange that I google the operator going through 2 pages of google nothing. Had to rumble through msdn for a bit to see what you were saying. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are called [Type Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx). From MSDN:

> Visual Basic supplies a set of identifier type characters, which you can use in a declaration to specify the data type of a variable or constant.

Here is the list, reprinted from the link:

```
Identifier type character    Data type    Example
---------------------------------------------------------------------    
 %                            Integer      Dim L% 
 &                            Long         Dim M& 
 @                            Decimal      Const W@ = 37.5 
 !                            Single       Dim Q! 
 #                            Double       Dim X# 
 $                            String       Dim V$ = "Secret"
```